# Why python3.3 can not use goagent?

Tags: python

My system :debian7+python3.3+goagent 3.01,
when i installed goagent ,and got a appid.

```
cd  /home/debian/goagent
python3.3   ./local/proxy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./local/proxy.py", line 31, in <module>
import gevent
File "/usr/local/python3.3.0/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gevent/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
from gevent.hub import get_hub
File "/usr/local/python3.3.0/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 9
except ImportError, ex:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the matter?

Comment: Probably because `goagent` doesn't support Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`except ImportError, ex:` is the old syntax for catching expressions. It's been deprecated in Python 2 since Python 2.6, and was removed entirely in Python 3. The new syntax is `except Exception as ex:`; see [PEP 3110](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/) for the rationale.

`gevent` [does not, at this point, support Python 3](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/issues/38). If you want to use it, you should use Python 2 instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
except ImportError, ex:
```

This syntax is incorrect in Python 3. You should use keyword `as`

```
except ImportError as ex:
```